# Haartraining, Why do i keep getting the error "unable to read negative images"

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

The dat file showing where the negatives are is as shown below:

```
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\1.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\2.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\3.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\4.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\5.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\6.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\7.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\8.png
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\NegativeNose\9.png
```

every time i run the haartraining i get the error:

```
"Error: Unspecified error (Unable to read negative images) in cvCreateTreeCascadeClassifier,"
```

any help would be greatly appreciated as i have been stuck on this for the past hour or two.

Comment: would be nice if you could provide code (maybe the part where you think the problem is) and describe how you call the classifier. It looks like an error due to wrong path of the images or incorrect files.

Comment: sorry, its "opencv_haartraining - data data -vec Noses.vec - bg NegativeNoses.dat -nstages 20 -minhitrate 0.9 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -npos 80 -nneg 9 -w 20 -h 20 -nonsym -mem 3072"

Comment: its that what you are referring to sorry if its not im new to this and am trying to teach myself.

Comment: I haven't worked on this for a while. this turorial helped me http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead make your entries in the bg file like--

1.png
2.png
3.png
4.png
....

That will do the trick

Regards