# Haartraining, error “unable to read negative images”

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

The txt file showing where the negatives are is as shown below:

```
C:\Users\medo\Desktop\ab\neg-0002.jpg 
C:\Users\medo\Desktop\ab\neg-0003.jpg 
C:\Users\medo\Desktop\ab\neg-0004.jpg 
C:\Users\medo\Desktop\ab\neg-0005.jpg
```

i use this code

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_haartraining.exe -data GT01\ -vec G01_442_2424_N.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 10 -numNeg 3019 -numStages 16 -nunSplits 2 -numOnsym -minhitrate 0.998 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -mem 1024 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

i search in google and found some answer

[like this in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291663/haartraining-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-error-unable-to-read-negative-images)

i dont understand what he mean

i just edit my code like he answer and its be like this

negative image txt file be

```
neg-0002.jpg
neg-0003.jpg
neg-0004.jpg
neg-0005.jpg
```

and i add all negative image in same folder but i still get

> unable to read negative images

Comment: The question seems to be unrelated to Matlab, please remove the tag.

Comment: Done ! ,, but i think in Matlab also use haarcascade xml